# Drupal 7 site with web services

Tags: php, web-services, drupal-7

I have a Drupal 7 site.
I want to create some web-services written in PHP, that uses Drupal's database. For example export/ import the users.

- Can I create the services under the Drupal site folder?
- Is there any module for that? or I just read the data from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [services module](https://drupal.org/project/services) to create your own RESTful service. There are several articles on the net on how to do this, e.g.:

- [This article](http://pingv.com/blog/an-introduction-drupal-7-restful-services)
- [A very detailed article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-drupal-web-service-project/) from IBM
- [Here](http://www.wdtutorials.com/2013/05/07/drupal-7-tutorial-web-services-basics-part-2) is a step-by-step video tutorial on services with CRUD operations
- You can find a lot of info, a description of the API and examples in the services module [documentation page](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/services)